# vertical merge of two columns into a single one

Tags: mysql

I have three columns as in the below image, and I would like to merge the two columns `values1` and `values2` into a single one.  What is the SQL code to do it?

[image]

Comment: This is the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22739841/mysql-combine-two-columns-into-one-column

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge 2 or more columns into one?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31010993/how-to-merge-2-or-more-columns-into-one)

Comment: I am not trying to concat two columns but i am trying to put one column on top of another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a `UNION` query:

```
SELECT nouns, values1 FROM yourTable
UNION ALL
(
    SELECT NULL, values2 FROM yourTable
)
```

**Demo here:**

## SQLFiddle

**Update:**

You could also use the `nouns` column instead of filling with `NULL`, e.g.

```
SELECT nouns, values1 FROM yourTable
UNION ALL
(
    SELECT nouns, values2 FROM yourTable
)
```

Comment: this code combines the three columns into one but I would like to combine only values1 and values2 and keep nouns as a separate columns

Comment: @user123123123 I updated my answer.  You can still use a `UNION` query I believe, but use `NULL` values as placeholders for missing values in the `nouns` column.

Comment: one last thing please, how to duplicate the the values of column 'nouns' where it returns null

Comment: I will update my answer one last time, however I get the feeling that you are treating MySQL as if it is a glorified Excel, which it is not.

Comment: I am new to sql but I was able to solve my problem using the code you showed me. thank you for your help